# How can I align select and input elements on a form?

Tags: html, select, layout, input, alignment

My text input seems center aligned but my select inputs are top-aligned.
How can I fix this and have them both be the same?

[image]

Current HTML code:

```
<td><input text-align="top" name="configuration[targets_attributes][0][name]" id="configuration_targets_attributes_0_name" size="30" value="bob" type="text"></td>
<td><li class="select input required" id="configuration_targets_attributes_0_maximum_fte_input"><select id="configuration_targets_attributes_0_maximum_fte" name="configuration[targets_attributes][0][maximum_fte]"><option value="1.0" selected="selected">1.0</option>
<option value="0.9">0.9</option>
<option value="0.8">0.8</option>
...
</select>
</li></td>
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle for this?

Comment: add a 5px margin to the top of your select boxes. plus why are you wrapping your selects in `<li>` elements as well as `<td>`'s? `<li>` should be wrapped in `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements not by themselves. And in this instance it's just more wasted markup as they seem to serve no purpose.

Comment: This question coming out from a person with 20.5k points. Nothing wrong or bad but little unusual.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by being more consistent with your containers. You put the input directly inside the td, but you put the select inside an li. Try putting them both in the same containers. You probably don't want to use an li right there since it's not in a list. So I would probably get rid of the li in the second td.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `text-align` HTML attribute, which, to my knowledge, doesn't exist. Instead, since you have this in a table, you should be using the CSS property `vertical-align: middle`.

You also have `<li>` elements directly inside your `<td>` tags, which I believe is also invalid. `<li>` elements can only be children of either `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags.

Having said that, using a `<table>` is not really appropriate for this use. It can be done, but there may be a better way, possibly using floated divs. Tables are meant for tabular data, not for layout. Or perhaps get rid of the table and use a `<ul>` with floated `<li>`tags.

Here is an example using a `<ul>` with floated `<li>` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/LU3VU/

Answer (score 0):

Must be your CSS. It works fine without any styling: http://jsfiddle.net/32mxD/1/

Also, as other suggested, from consistency and best practice point of view, not a good idea to have `LI` within a `TD` and then have Select within the `LI`

Answer (score 0):

As Callan said, get rid of the li within the td

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/s8KR3/

If you are still having problems with elements on the same row being on a different height, you should use

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

in your css. Note that if it isn't aligned properly, it's probably due to another css rule you already added, but didn't post here.